# Is it possible to use DataSet.ReadXml to fill a DataSet while ignoring the case of the xml fields?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, schema

I need to read an xml file into a DataSet whose schema may have changed since I wrote the xml file. My approach so far has been to call

`myDataSet.ReadXml(myStreamReader, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema)`,

which successfully pulls the xml data into the new schema (deleting, of course, any removed fields and their data).

The issue I've ran into, however, is that **XML nodes/field names are case sensitive**. Therefore, if a DBA decides he needs to change a field name to be all lower case, the matching field in my XML is dropped along with all of its data when it gets read in.

My question is, is it possible to hack the ReadXml method to ignore the case of the nodes? And if not, is there another way to handle always reading my xml into the most up-to-date schema?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the entire xml into  a string.  Then make the entire string uppercase. and put into a stringreader.  Finally have ReadXml(stringreader).

Comment: That won't work in my case because some of the field values are text and their case needs to be preserved.